# return a view or redirect after ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, redirect

how i cant redirect o return a view after a ajax request.

i try validate the request and after (if the request are ok) return a view, but this dont work, i try redirect to the new route but dont work too.

this is my controller:

```
 public function searchActivity(Request $request){

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'search' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required_with:search|required|date|date_format:d-m-y|after:yesterday'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()){

        return response()->json([
            'sucess' => false,
            'errors' => $validator->errors()->toArray(),
            'data' => $request->all()
        ]);
    }else{

$queries =  DB::table('activities')->where('name', $request->search)->orWhere('City', $request->search)->paginate(1);

        return redirect()->route('ActivitiesResults', ['results' => $queries]);
    }
```

JS code:

```
    function selectDate(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
    });
}

function searchActivity(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(event);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: searchRoute,
        data: {
            search: $('.search').val(),
            date: $('#datepicker').val(),
            _token: $('#token').val()
        },

        dataType : "json",

        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success){

              console.log(data)

            }else{
                console.log(data.errors);

            }
        }
    })
}
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: I think is because you are redirecting at the PHP, but you are using AJAX, so I might be a good idea to try using `window.open("URL","_self");` at your JS.

Answer (score 3):

you need to change your php code

```
if ($validator->fails()){

    return response()->json([
        'sucess' => false,
        'errors' => $validator->errors()->toArray(),
        'data' => $request->all()
    ]);
}else{
    return response()->json([
        'sucess' => true,
        'what_you_want' => ''
    ]);    }
```

change your ajax code like this

```
  success: function (data) {
        if (data.success){

          //console.log(data)
         window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

        }else{
            console.log(data.errors);
            window.location.replace("http://google.com");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I want to display in another view the values of $ request, as I should put after another in the php code?

Comment: i want return a new view With the results of a search. I already edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

use `header("url)` or `window.location.href="url"` in you success funciton.